# How to Convert PSD into PNG, using Python Wand / ImageMagick?

Tags: python, imagemagick, png, psd, wand

I tried converting PSD to PNG, but as I save the PNG, Wand (wand-0.4.0-py2.7) spits out all layers inside the PSD as separate PNG files (the last file saved is the one I want). So how to correctly convert from PSD to PNG?

```
# Convert a large PSD to small PNG thumbnail
myImage = Image(filename="test.psd")
myImage.resize(100, 100)
myImage.format = "png"
myImage.save(filename="test.png")
```

found related solution:

- http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=16550
- https://github.com/dahlia/wand/issues/22photoshop

but not sure how it can be done in Python (I'm new to Python)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work just well and *fast* for both read and write:

```
# Convert a large PSD to small PNG thumbnail
myImage = Image(filename="test.psd[0]")
myImage.format = "png"
myImage.sample(100, 100)
myImage.save(filename="test.png")
```

Because Wand is only reading 1 layer instead of all the layers inside the PSD.

- the key is to append **[0]** to the filename string.
- after testing, **[0]** will get the final composited image from PSD.
- and all other numbers don't seem to make a clear sense as to which layers they represent. in my case, [1] is the 2nd layer from the bottom, and [2] the 3rd, etc. so probably a good idea not to extract layers that way.

For more complicated operations with PSD files, you may consider Python psd-tools (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psd-tools). but from my initial testing, it reads PSD rather slow (maybe because it reads the entire PSD).

---

### Additional Application with Qt

It'd be useful if you want to load PSD (or other image formats) into Qt UI. The concept is to convert image loaded by Wand into **image string**, and send that **image string** to QImage.

```
# load the image first
myImage = Image(filename=r"c:\test.psd[0]")
myImage.format = "png"
myImage.sample(100, 100)
aBlob = myImage.make_blob()

# load the image data into QImage
myQImage = QtGui.QImage.fromData( aBlob )
myQPixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage( myQImage )
target_QLabel.setPixmap( myQPixmap )
```